# bashrc file - "command not found" when defining function to print current Git branch

Tags: git, bash

When I save this to my **~/.bashrc** file I get an error upon running **source ~/.bashrc** ? Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
# Git branch in prompt.

parse_git_branch () {
        git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}
```

ERROR

```
$ source  ~/.bashrc

: command not found
'bash: /Users/RGA/.bashrc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'bash: /Users/RGA/.bashrc: line 3: `parse_git_branch () {
```

NOTE: the only thing in my **~/.bash_profile** is:
 **source ~/.bashrc**

UPDATE TO INCLUDE BASH VERSION (OSX 10.9)

```
$ bash --version 

GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)  
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, and in fact it works fine for me, albeit with a newer `bash`.  You could try removing the space between the function name and parentheses.

Comment: DOS line endings are an incredibly common source of errors. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something suspicious about the error output.  Let's look at the first two errors, and think about the fact that your file has a comment as its first line:

> ```
> : command not found
> ```

What command might this be?  There is no command name here.  Hmm...

> ```
> 'bash: /Users/RGA/.bashrc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `{
> ```

And: why is there a closing single quote at the beginning of the line, and then an opening single (back)quote near the end of the line, just before the open brace `{`?

What if each of these first three lines ends with a mostly-invisible character that, when printed, tells the computer to move back to the first position of the current line?  Let's represent this hypothetical mostly-invisible character as `\r`, which stands for "invisible character that causes a position-return-to-beginning-of-line".  Then the command that is not found is this invisible-character `\r` command, and the syntax error occurs because the open brace `{` is followed by `\r`.

Perhaps we should write this character instead as `^M`, where the `M` stands for "motion to beginning of line".  Perhaps your first three lines are *not*:

```
# Git branch in prompt.

parse_git_branch () {
```

but rather:

```
# Git branch in prompt.^M
^M
parse_git_branch () {^M
```

Perhaps you should view the file with an editor that does not hide carriage-returns `\r` (aka `^M`) that occur before newlines `\n`.

(If your editor is `vim` you can use this setting, which some will probably call overkill, but which I like:

```
set ffs=unix " disable "file format = dos" detection
```

Or you can set the file format back once the file is open, so that `vim` won't re-add the ^M at the end of each line.  If you use some other editor, find out how to make it stop doing automatic DOS-style line endings.)

Comment: That's not what the `M` in `^M` stands for (although it does make for a nice mnemonic). Control characters are represented by the character which, if you clear the 6th bit, gives you the control character. M is ASCII 77; carriage return is ASCII 13 = 77 & 0xbf.

Comment: @chepner: I know, I was just playing with it.  Besides the control series there's also the old fashioned meta series (these days, replaced with ISO Latin 1 or other code pages, but still in vis(3) in the form I suggested back in the 1990s: `\^C` means control, `\M-C` means meta, and `\M^C` means meta-control).

Comment: Thanks @torek - it was indeed a hidden character that was causing all my fuss. I recreated my bashrc file from a blank txt file and typed the necessary code back... everything worked fine. I guess something carried over when I copied it from somewhere or another file